# Change UIPicker color

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uipickerview

How can I change the color of my picker?

I don't wish to change the font or the text. My picker is populate and works exactly how I want it, what I want to do is change the color from black to my custom white.

Comment: Change the color of what : the font, the background, the selected item, the unselected items?

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at: http://makeapppie.com/tag/uipickerview-in-swift/

If you want to change your title color of each element you could implement:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = pickerData[row]
    var myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
    return myTitle
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = pickerData[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white])
    return myTitle
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed and enabled me to use white text in a picker view on a black background. Thank you

Comment: @Youri Nooijen, great for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

***For both Date picker and Normal Picker**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   pickerView.setValue(UIColor.blue, forKey: "textColor")
   pickerView.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "backgroundColor")
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.0

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let titleData = arrayOfPickerData[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [.font:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 15.0)!, .foregroundColor:UIColor.white]))
    return myTitle
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want ***more control*** customizing each element in the picker...

Use [UIPickerViewDelegate's](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate) "*viewForRow*" method.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var label: UILabel
    if let view = view as? UILabel { label = view }
    else { label = UILabel() }

    label.textColor = UIColor.blue
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "My-Custom-Font", size: 20) // or UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    label.text = getTextForPicker(atRow: row) // implemented elsewhere

    return label
}
```

Obviously the view you're returning could be more complex than just a UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0 with Multiple Components in UIPickerView

Each "component" is the list that show in the UIPickerView that you design. For example if you have the something like the following: A list of names in an array and another list of ages in an array and both are displayed such that you pick a persons name and their age. 
  The first component 'names' in forComponent is component == 0;
  The second component 'age' in forComponent is componennt == 1;
  and so on based on the number of components you have listed.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    if component == 0 {
        let nameData = namesArray[row]
        let myNameData = NSAttributedString(string: nameData, attributes: [.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
        return myNameData
    } else {
        let ageData = ageArray[row]
        let myAgeData = NSAttributedString(string: ageData, attributes: [.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
        return myAgeData
    }

}
```