# ios uipickerview change text color upon tap

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipickerview, textcolor

Is it possible to change a uipickerview's text color on the fly?

I want to change uipickerview's textColor upon a triple tap:

```
let triple_tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tripleTapped))
triple_tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
view.addGestureRecognizer(triple_tap)


func tripleTapped() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor?.inverse()        
    myLabel.textColor = myLabel.textColor?.inverse()
    myPicker.backgroundColor = myPicker.backgroundColor?.inverse()
    // myPicker 
    // can't figure out out how to change the text color here? is it possible?
}
```

My pickerview delegate:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    let titleData = NSString(format: "%@", myData[row])
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 20.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGray])
    pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    return pickerLabel

}
```

Comment: Which UIPickerView delegate method are you currently using for the picker view's text?

Comment: is it duplicated? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243564/change-uipicker-color-swift)

Comment: Just update your `viewForRow` to set the desired colors on the label then in `tripleTapped` you can reload the picker view.

Comment: @rmaddy re declare the pickerview delegate in tripleTapped in order to set the colors and then reload?

Comment: Not at all. Simply update the implementation of your existing `viewForRow` method so it sets the label's colors as needed. Then in your `tripleTapped` method you set a flag and reload the picker view's components.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks very much, should have been obvious :| If you post your comment as a answer I'd accept